# Safari does not respect @Keyframes opacity/fill

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari

The following animation is working in the newest Chrome and FF, but Safari does not follow the defined @Keyframes. Can you help fixing this?

The issue is that Safari opacity does not follow the defined @Keyframes and "spreads out" the fill opacity during the full animation instead of respecting the @Keyframese at 0%, 30%, 90% and 100% to control the opacity. The intention is that the fill opacity should only kick in from Keyframe 90% and 100% of the animation time, not from the beginning.

Chrome - Good: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dszr4.jpg

Safari - Bad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCIEK.jpg

```css
path.syncron {
    stroke: #2d3f50;
    fill: #2d3f50;
    stroke-dasharray: 266;
    opacity: 10;
    -moz-animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    -webkit-animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
}

path.dot {
    stroke: #e64d3c;
    fill: #e64d3c;
    stroke-dasharray: 52;
    opacity: 10;
    -moz-animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    -webkit-animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
}

/*Syncron Logo animation*/
@keyframes syncron {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0);}
    100% {opacity: 10; fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes syncron {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0);}
    100% {opacity: 1.0; fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes syncron {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0);}
    100% {opacity: 10; fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@keyframes dot {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0);}
    100% {opacity: 10; fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes dot {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0);}
    100% {opacity: 10; fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes dot {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0);}
    100% {opacity: 10; fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="409.11px" height="77.54" viewBox="0 0 409.11 105.75">
        <style type="text/css">
            .syncron{fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            .dot{fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        </style>
        <title>.syncron Logo | All rights reserved (c) 2019 Syncron</title>
        <a class="hide-on-fallback">
        <g>
            <path class="syncron" d="M52.97,69.78c7.4,0,11.11-2.37,11.11-7.1c0-1.47-0.73-2.58-2.2-3.35c-1.47-0.77-3.32-1.45-5.55-2.05
                c-2.24-0.6-4.65-1.22-7.25-1.85c-2.6-0.63-5.02-1.52-7.25-2.65c-2.24-1.13-4.09-2.62-5.55-4.45c-1.47-1.83-2.2-4.08-2.2-6.75
                c0-2.67,0.4-4.97,1.2-6.9c0.8-1.93,2-3.6,3.6-5c3.53-3,8.44-4.5,14.71-4.5c5,0,9.84,0.83,14.51,2.5c0.93,0.33,1.65,0.87,2.15,1.6
                c0.5,0.73,0.75,1.55,0.75,2.45s-0.38,1.75-1.15,2.55c-0.77,0.8-1.52,1.2-2.25,1.2c-0.73,0-1.64-0.17-2.7-0.5
                c-3.2-1-6.7-1.5-10.51-1.5s-6.69,0.67-8.65,2c-1.97,1.34-2.95,2.94-2.95,4.8c0,1.87,0.75,3.25,2.25,4.15
                c1.5,0.9,3.35,1.65,5.55,2.25c2.2,0.6,4.62,1.2,7.25,1.8c2.63,0.6,5.05,1.44,7.25,2.5c5.2,2.67,7.8,6.8,7.8,12.41
                c0,4.27-1.6,7.74-4.8,10.41c-3.47,2.94-8.31,4.4-14.51,4.4c-6.74,0-12.81-1.5-18.21-4.5c-1.14-0.8-1.7-1.8-1.7-3
                c0-1.2,0.37-2.22,1.1-3.05c0.73-0.83,1.53-1.25,2.4-1.25c0.87,0,1.9,0.27,3.1,0.8C44.13,68.92,48.36,69.78,52.97,69.78z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M126.51,27.01c0.87,0.9,1.3,1.84,1.3,2.8c0,0.97-0.1,1.69-0.3,2.15L100.19,97.6c-0.87,2.07-2.27,3.1-4.2,3.1
                c-1.2,0-2.22-0.43-3.05-1.3c-0.83-0.87-1.25-1.74-1.25-2.6c0-0.87,0.1-1.57,0.3-2.1l6.5-16.71L79.68,32.16
                c-0.27-0.67-0.4-1.47-0.4-2.4c0-0.93,0.43-1.85,1.3-2.75c0.87-0.9,1.83-1.35,2.9-1.35c2.2,0,3.7,0.93,4.5,2.8l15.41,38.22
                l15.71-38.02c0.87-2,2.27-3,4.2-3C124.57,25.66,125.64,26.11,126.51,27.01z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M163.63,33.56c-5.87,0-11.34,3.2-16.41,9.61v30.02c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3
                c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26c0-1.33,0.43-2.43,1.3-3.3c0.87-0.87,1.93-1.3,3.2-1.3
                c1.27,0,2.35,0.43,3.25,1.3c0.9,0.87,1.35,1.97,1.35,3.3v4.1c2.67-2.8,4.97-4.77,6.9-5.9c3.8-2.2,7.42-3.3,10.86-3.3
                c3.43,0,6.25,0.52,8.45,1.55c2.2,1.04,4.07,2.45,5.6,4.25c3.13,3.67,4.7,8.27,4.7,13.81v28.42c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2
                c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V45.77c0-3.8-0.85-6.79-2.55-8.96
                C170.38,34.65,167.56,33.56,163.63,33.56z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M223.26,69.68c3.74,0,7.3-0.93,10.71-2.8c1.2-0.67,2.27-1,3.2-1c0.93,0,1.77,0.43,2.5,1.3
                c0.73,0.87,1.1,1.9,1.1,3.1c0,1.2-0.77,2.3-2.3,3.3c-4.74,3.07-10.07,4.6-16.01,4.6c-7.4,0-13.64-2.33-18.71-7
                c-5.34-4.94-8-11.44-8-19.51c0-8.07,2.67-14.57,8-19.51c5.07-4.67,11.31-7,18.71-7c4,0,7.29,0.52,9.86,1.55
                c2.57,1.04,4.62,2.05,6.15,3.05c1.53,1,2.3,2.1,2.3,3.3s-0.37,2.24-1.1,3.1c-0.73,0.87-1.47,1.3-2.2,1.3c-1.14,0-2.3-0.33-3.5-1
                c-3.4-1.87-6.97-2.8-10.71-2.8c-5.87,0-10.41,1.65-13.61,4.95c-3.2,3.3-4.8,7.65-4.8,13.06c0,5.4,1.6,9.76,4.8,13.06
                C212.85,68.03,217.39,69.68,223.26,69.68z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M261.78,34.56c4.67-6.27,9.91-9.41,15.71-9.41h0.5c1.27,0,2.32,0.43,3.15,1.3c0.83,0.87,1.25,1.95,1.25,3.25
                s-0.43,2.34-1.3,3.1c-0.87,0.77-1.97,1.15-3.3,1.15h-0.5c-3.34,0-6.32,0.82-8.96,2.45c-2.64,1.64-4.82,3.75-6.55,6.35v30.42
                c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26
                c0-1.27,0.43-2.35,1.3-3.25c0.87-0.9,1.93-1.35,3.2-1.35c1.27,0,2.35,0.45,3.25,1.35c0.9,0.9,1.35,1.99,1.35,3.25V34.56z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M313.91,25.16c7.74,0,13.94,2.44,18.61,7.3c4.67,4.94,7,11.34,7,19.21c0,7.87-2.34,14.28-7,19.21
                c-4.67,4.87-10.87,7.3-18.61,7.3c-7.8,0-14.01-2.43-18.61-7.3c-4.67-4.87-7-11.27-7-19.21c0-7.94,2.33-14.34,7-19.21
                C299.9,27.59,306.11,25.16,313.91,25.16z M302.76,65.73c1.57,1.44,3.33,2.49,5.3,3.15c1.97,0.67,3.9,1,5.8,1c1.9,0,3.83-0.33,5.8-1
                c1.97-0.67,3.75-1.7,5.35-3.1c3.6-3.27,5.4-8,5.4-14.21c0-6-1.8-10.67-5.4-14.01c-3-2.73-6.7-4.1-11.11-4.1
                c-7.2,0-12.21,3.24-15.01,9.71c-1,2.34-1.5,5.15-1.5,8.46c0,3.3,0.5,6.12,1.5,8.46S301.19,64.3,302.76,65.73z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M377.75,33.56c-5.87,0-11.34,3.2-16.41,9.61v30.02c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2s-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3
                c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26c0-1.33,0.43-2.43,1.3-3.3c0.87-0.87,1.93-1.3,3.2-1.3
                c1.27,0,2.35,0.43,3.25,1.3c0.9,0.87,1.35,1.97,1.35,3.3v4.1c2.67-2.8,4.97-4.77,6.9-5.9c3.8-2.2,7.42-3.3,10.86-3.3
                s6.25,0.52,8.46,1.55c2.2,1.04,4.07,2.45,5.6,4.25c3.13,3.67,4.7,8.27,4.7,13.81v28.42c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2
                s-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.33-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V45.77c0-3.8-0.85-6.79-2.55-8.96
                C384.5,34.65,381.68,33.56,377.75,33.56z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path class="dot" d="M16.31,62.08h4c1.93,0,3.28,0.37,4.05,1.1c0.77,0.73,1.15,2.07,1.15,4v4.8c0,1.94-0.38,3.29-1.15,4.05
                c-0.77,0.77-2.12,1.15-4.05,1.15h-4c-1.94,0-3.29-0.38-4.05-1.15c-0.77-0.77-1.15-2.12-1.15-4.05v-4.8c0-1.93,0.38-3.27,1.15-4
                C13.02,62.45,14.37,62.08,16.31,62.08z"/>
        </g>
        </a>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Please define exactly what "Safari does not wanna play nice" means? When you say Safari 12, do you mean this is a regression from some previous version of Safari? Have you thought of reporting a webkit bug to the webkit bug tracking system?

Comment: The opacity goes from 0-100% during the full duration of the animation. Whilst the intended way and how it works in Chrome/FF is to use the @Keyframse 0%, 30%, 90% and 100%. Where the opacify kicks in from 90%-100% of the animation time, not from the beginning.

Comment: Regarding version 12, then I mentioned that to be more specific. It’s not because it worked in previous versions. I didn’t test this. I’m not sure it’s a bug. At least I would like to get a second opinion before concluding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The solution was to define `fill: rbga()` for all the `@keyframes`. It seems that Chrome and Firefox were more forgiving than Safari. So I added `fill: rbga()` and as a bonus I also added a `stroke-opacity` value to counter what @Sean mentioned above when setting opacity values to single digits via `rgba()`

The final code that works on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Mobile browsers are:

```css
path.syncron {
 stroke: #2d3f50;
 fill: #2d3f50;
 stroke-dasharray: 266;
 opacity: 1;
 -moz-animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
 -webkit-animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
 animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
}

path.dot {
 stroke: #e64d3c;
 fill: #e64d3c;
 stroke-dasharray: 52;
 opacity: 1;
 -moz-animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
 -webkit-animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
 animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
}

/*Syncron Logo animation*/
@keyframes syncron {
 0% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
 30% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
 90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 1;}
 100% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes syncron {
 0% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
 30% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
 90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 1;}
 100% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes syncron {
 0% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
 30% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
 90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0); stroke-opacity: 1;}
 100% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@keyframes dot {
 0% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
 30% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
 90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 1;}
 100% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes dot {
 0% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
 30% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
 90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 1;}
 100% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes dot {
 0% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
 30% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
 90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0); stroke-opacity: 1;}
 100% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="409.11px" height="77.54" viewBox="0 0 409.11 105.75">
   <style type="text/css">
    .syncron {
     fill: none;
     stroke: none;
     stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .dot {
     fill: none;
     stroke: none;
     stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }
   </style>
   <title>.syncron Logo | All rights reserved (c) 2019 Syncron</title>
   <a class="hide-on-fallback">
    <g>
     <path class="syncron"
      d="M52.97,69.78c7.4,0,11.11-2.37,11.11-7.1c0-1.47-0.73-2.58-2.2-3.35c-1.47-0.77-3.32-1.45-5.55-2.05
    c-2.24-0.6-4.65-1.22-7.25-1.85c-2.6-0.63-5.02-1.52-7.25-2.65c-2.24-1.13-4.09-2.62-5.55-4.45c-1.47-1.83-2.2-4.08-2.2-6.75
    c0-2.67,0.4-4.97,1.2-6.9c0.8-1.93,2-3.6,3.6-5c3.53-3,8.44-4.5,14.71-4.5c5,0,9.84,0.83,14.51,2.5c0.93,0.33,1.65,0.87,2.15,1.6
    c0.5,0.73,0.75,1.55,0.75,2.45s-0.38,1.75-1.15,2.55c-0.77,0.8-1.52,1.2-2.25,1.2c-0.73,0-1.64-0.17-2.7-0.5
    c-3.2-1-6.7-1.5-10.51-1.5s-6.69,0.67-8.65,2c-1.97,1.34-2.95,2.94-2.95,4.8c0,1.87,0.75,3.25,2.25,4.15
    c1.5,0.9,3.35,1.65,5.55,2.25c2.2,0.6,4.62,1.2,7.25,1.8c2.63,0.6,5.05,1.44,7.25,2.5c5.2,2.67,7.8,6.8,7.8,12.41
    c0,4.27-1.6,7.74-4.8,10.41c-3.47,2.94-8.31,4.4-14.51,4.4c-6.74,0-12.81-1.5-18.21-4.5c-1.14-0.8-1.7-1.8-1.7-3
    c0-1.2,0.37-2.22,1.1-3.05c0.73-0.83,1.53-1.25,2.4-1.25c0.87,0,1.9,0.27,3.1,0.8C44.13,68.92,48.36,69.78,52.97,69.78z" />
     <path class="syncron" d="M126.51,27.01c0.87,0.9,1.3,1.84,1.3,2.8c0,0.97-0.1,1.69-0.3,2.15L100.19,97.6c-0.87,2.07-2.27,3.1-4.2,3.1
    c-1.2,0-2.22-0.43-3.05-1.3c-0.83-0.87-1.25-1.74-1.25-2.6c0-0.87,0.1-1.57,0.3-2.1l6.5-16.71L79.68,32.16
    c-0.27-0.67-0.4-1.47-0.4-2.4c0-0.93,0.43-1.85,1.3-2.75c0.87-0.9,1.83-1.35,2.9-1.35c2.2,0,3.7,0.93,4.5,2.8l15.41,38.22
    l15.71-38.02c0.87-2,2.27-3,4.2-3C124.57,25.66,125.64,26.11,126.51,27.01z" />
     <path class="syncron" d="M163.63,33.56c-5.87,0-11.34,3.2-16.41,9.61v30.02c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3
    c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26c0-1.33,0.43-2.43,1.3-3.3c0.87-0.87,1.93-1.3,3.2-1.3
    c1.27,0,2.35,0.43,3.25,1.3c0.9,0.87,1.35,1.97,1.35,3.3v4.1c2.67-2.8,4.97-4.77,6.9-5.9c3.8-2.2,7.42-3.3,10.86-3.3
    c3.43,0,6.25,0.52,8.45,1.55c2.2,1.04,4.07,2.45,5.6,4.25c3.13,3.67,4.7,8.27,4.7,13.81v28.42c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2
    c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V45.77c0-3.8-0.85-6.79-2.55-8.96
    C170.38,34.65,167.56,33.56,163.63,33.56z" />
     <path class="syncron" d="M223.26,69.68c3.74,0,7.3-0.93,10.71-2.8c1.2-0.67,2.27-1,3.2-1c0.93,0,1.77,0.43,2.5,1.3
    c0.73,0.87,1.1,1.9,1.1,3.1c0,1.2-0.77,2.3-2.3,3.3c-4.74,3.07-10.07,4.6-16.01,4.6c-7.4,0-13.64-2.33-18.71-7
    c-5.34-4.94-8-11.44-8-19.51c0-8.07,2.67-14.57,8-19.51c5.07-4.67,11.31-7,18.71-7c4,0,7.29,0.52,9.86,1.55
    c2.57,1.04,4.62,2.05,6.15,3.05c1.53,1,2.3,2.1,2.3,3.3s-0.37,2.24-1.1,3.1c-0.73,0.87-1.47,1.3-2.2,1.3c-1.14,0-2.3-0.33-3.5-1
    c-3.4-1.87-6.97-2.8-10.71-2.8c-5.87,0-10.41,1.65-13.61,4.95c-3.2,3.3-4.8,7.65-4.8,13.06c0,5.4,1.6,9.76,4.8,13.06
    C212.85,68.03,217.39,69.68,223.26,69.68z" />
     <path class="syncron"
      d="M261.78,34.56c4.67-6.27,9.91-9.41,15.71-9.41h0.5c1.27,0,2.32,0.43,3.15,1.3c0.83,0.87,1.25,1.95,1.25,3.25
    s-0.43,2.34-1.3,3.1c-0.87,0.77-1.97,1.15-3.3,1.15h-0.5c-3.34,0-6.32,0.82-8.96,2.45c-2.64,1.64-4.82,3.75-6.55,6.35v30.42
    c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26
    c0-1.27,0.43-2.35,1.3-3.25c0.87-0.9,1.93-1.35,3.2-1.35c1.27,0,2.35,0.45,3.25,1.35c0.9,0.9,1.35,1.99,1.35,3.25V34.56z" />
     <path class="syncron" d="M313.91,25.16c7.74,0,13.94,2.44,18.61,7.3c4.67,4.94,7,11.34,7,19.21c0,7.87-2.34,14.28-7,19.21
    c-4.67,4.87-10.87,7.3-18.61,7.3c-7.8,0-14.01-2.43-18.61-7.3c-4.67-4.87-7-11.27-7-19.21c0-7.94,2.33-14.34,7-19.21
    C299.9,27.59,306.11,25.16,313.91,25.16z M302.76,65.73c1.57,1.44,3.33,2.49,5.3,3.15c1.97,0.67,3.9,1,5.8,1c1.9,0,3.83-0.33,5.8-1
    c1.97-0.67,3.75-1.7,5.35-3.1c3.6-3.27,5.4-8,5.4-14.21c0-6-1.8-10.67-5.4-14.01c-3-2.73-6.7-4.1-11.11-4.1
    c-7.2,0-12.21,3.24-15.01,9.71c-1,2.34-1.5,5.15-1.5,8.46c0,3.3,0.5,6.12,1.5,8.46S301.19,64.3,302.76,65.73z" />
     <path class="syncron" d="M377.75,33.56c-5.87,0-11.34,3.2-16.41,9.61v30.02c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2s-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3
    c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26c0-1.33,0.43-2.43,1.3-3.3c0.87-0.87,1.93-1.3,3.2-1.3
    c1.27,0,2.35,0.43,3.25,1.3c0.9,0.87,1.35,1.97,1.35,3.3v4.1c2.67-2.8,4.97-4.77,6.9-5.9c3.8-2.2,7.42-3.3,10.86-3.3
    s6.25,0.52,8.46,1.55c2.2,1.04,4.07,2.45,5.6,4.25c3.13,3.67,4.7,8.27,4.7,13.81v28.42c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2
    s-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.33-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V45.77c0-3.8-0.85-6.79-2.55-8.96
    C384.5,34.65,381.68,33.56,377.75,33.56z" />
    </g>
    <g>
     <path class="dot" d="M16.31,62.08h4c1.93,0,3.28,0.37,4.05,1.1c0.77,0.73,1.15,2.07,1.15,4v4.8c0,1.94-0.38,3.29-1.15,4.05
    c-0.77,0.77-2.12,1.15-4.05,1.15h-4c-1.94,0-3.29-0.38-4.05-1.15c-0.77-0.77-1.15-2.12-1.15-4.05v-4.8c0-1.93,0.38-3.27,1.15-4
    C13.02,62.45,14.37,62.08,16.31,62.08z" />
    </g>
   </a>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `opacity` CSS property should only be set to a value between `0` and `1`. Zero is completely transparent and one is completely opaque. See the [MD docs for opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). You're setting it to `10` in several places, which is likely the cause of the unexpected behavior.

Try changing those instances of `10` to `1`:

```css
path.syncron {
    stroke: #2d3f50;
    fill: #2d3f50;
    stroke-dasharray: 266;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    -webkit-animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    animation: syncron 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
}

path.dot {
    stroke: #e64d3c;
    fill: #e64d3c;
    stroke-dasharray: 52;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    -webkit-animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
    animation: dot 2s cubic-bezier(0,0.23,1,0.1);
}

/*Syncron Logo animation*/
@keyframes syncron {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0);}
    100% {opacity: 1; fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes syncron {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0);}
    100% {opacity: 1; fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes syncron {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 266;}
    90% {fill: rgba(45,63,80,0);}
    100% {opacity: 1; fill: rgba(45,63,80,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@keyframes dot {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0);}
    100% {opacity: 1; fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes dot {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0);}
    100% {opacity: 1; fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes dot {
    0% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    30% {opacity: 0; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 52;}
    90% {fill: rgba(230,77,60,0);}
    100% {opacity: 1; fill: rgba(230,77,60,1); stroke-dasharray: 0;}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="409.11px" height="77.54" viewBox="0 0 409.11 105.75">
        <style type="text/css">
            .syncron{fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            .dot{fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        </style>
        <title>.syncron Logo | All rights reserved (c) 2019 Syncron</title>
        <a class="hide-on-fallback">
        <g>
            <path class="syncron" d="M52.97,69.78c7.4,0,11.11-2.37,11.11-7.1c0-1.47-0.73-2.58-2.2-3.35c-1.47-0.77-3.32-1.45-5.55-2.05
                c-2.24-0.6-4.65-1.22-7.25-1.85c-2.6-0.63-5.02-1.52-7.25-2.65c-2.24-1.13-4.09-2.62-5.55-4.45c-1.47-1.83-2.2-4.08-2.2-6.75
                c0-2.67,0.4-4.97,1.2-6.9c0.8-1.93,2-3.6,3.6-5c3.53-3,8.44-4.5,14.71-4.5c5,0,9.84,0.83,14.51,2.5c0.93,0.33,1.65,0.87,2.15,1.6
                c0.5,0.73,0.75,1.55,0.75,2.45s-0.38,1.75-1.15,2.55c-0.77,0.8-1.52,1.2-2.25,1.2c-0.73,0-1.64-0.17-2.7-0.5
                c-3.2-1-6.7-1.5-10.51-1.5s-6.69,0.67-8.65,2c-1.97,1.34-2.95,2.94-2.95,4.8c0,1.87,0.75,3.25,2.25,4.15
                c1.5,0.9,3.35,1.65,5.55,2.25c2.2,0.6,4.62,1.2,7.25,1.8c2.63,0.6,5.05,1.44,7.25,2.5c5.2,2.67,7.8,6.8,7.8,12.41
                c0,4.27-1.6,7.74-4.8,10.41c-3.47,2.94-8.31,4.4-14.51,4.4c-6.74,0-12.81-1.5-18.21-4.5c-1.14-0.8-1.7-1.8-1.7-3
                c0-1.2,0.37-2.22,1.1-3.05c0.73-0.83,1.53-1.25,2.4-1.25c0.87,0,1.9,0.27,3.1,0.8C44.13,68.92,48.36,69.78,52.97,69.78z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M126.51,27.01c0.87,0.9,1.3,1.84,1.3,2.8c0,0.97-0.1,1.69-0.3,2.15L100.19,97.6c-0.87,2.07-2.27,3.1-4.2,3.1
                c-1.2,0-2.22-0.43-3.05-1.3c-0.83-0.87-1.25-1.74-1.25-2.6c0-0.87,0.1-1.57,0.3-2.1l6.5-16.71L79.68,32.16
                c-0.27-0.67-0.4-1.47-0.4-2.4c0-0.93,0.43-1.85,1.3-2.75c0.87-0.9,1.83-1.35,2.9-1.35c2.2,0,3.7,0.93,4.5,2.8l15.41,38.22
                l15.71-38.02c0.87-2,2.27-3,4.2-3C124.57,25.66,125.64,26.11,126.51,27.01z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M163.63,33.56c-5.87,0-11.34,3.2-16.41,9.61v30.02c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3
                c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26c0-1.33,0.43-2.43,1.3-3.3c0.87-0.87,1.93-1.3,3.2-1.3
                c1.27,0,2.35,0.43,3.25,1.3c0.9,0.87,1.35,1.97,1.35,3.3v4.1c2.67-2.8,4.97-4.77,6.9-5.9c3.8-2.2,7.42-3.3,10.86-3.3
                c3.43,0,6.25,0.52,8.45,1.55c2.2,1.04,4.07,2.45,5.6,4.25c3.13,3.67,4.7,8.27,4.7,13.81v28.42c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2
                c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V45.77c0-3.8-0.85-6.79-2.55-8.96
                C170.38,34.65,167.56,33.56,163.63,33.56z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M223.26,69.68c3.74,0,7.3-0.93,10.71-2.8c1.2-0.67,2.27-1,3.2-1c0.93,0,1.77,0.43,2.5,1.3
                c0.73,0.87,1.1,1.9,1.1,3.1c0,1.2-0.77,2.3-2.3,3.3c-4.74,3.07-10.07,4.6-16.01,4.6c-7.4,0-13.64-2.33-18.71-7
                c-5.34-4.94-8-11.44-8-19.51c0-8.07,2.67-14.57,8-19.51c5.07-4.67,11.31-7,18.71-7c4,0,7.29,0.52,9.86,1.55
                c2.57,1.04,4.62,2.05,6.15,3.05c1.53,1,2.3,2.1,2.3,3.3s-0.37,2.24-1.1,3.1c-0.73,0.87-1.47,1.3-2.2,1.3c-1.14,0-2.3-0.33-3.5-1
                c-3.4-1.87-6.97-2.8-10.71-2.8c-5.87,0-10.41,1.65-13.61,4.95c-3.2,3.3-4.8,7.65-4.8,13.06c0,5.4,1.6,9.76,4.8,13.06
                C212.85,68.03,217.39,69.68,223.26,69.68z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M261.78,34.56c4.67-6.27,9.91-9.41,15.71-9.41h0.5c1.27,0,2.32,0.43,3.15,1.3c0.83,0.87,1.25,1.95,1.25,3.25
                s-0.43,2.34-1.3,3.1c-0.87,0.77-1.97,1.15-3.3,1.15h-0.5c-3.34,0-6.32,0.82-8.96,2.45c-2.64,1.64-4.82,3.75-6.55,6.35v30.42
                c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2c-0.9,0.87-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26
                c0-1.27,0.43-2.35,1.3-3.25c0.87-0.9,1.93-1.35,3.2-1.35c1.27,0,2.35,0.45,3.25,1.35c0.9,0.9,1.35,1.99,1.35,3.25V34.56z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M313.91,25.16c7.74,0,13.94,2.44,18.61,7.3c4.67,4.94,7,11.34,7,19.21c0,7.87-2.34,14.28-7,19.21
                c-4.67,4.87-10.87,7.3-18.61,7.3c-7.8,0-14.01-2.43-18.61-7.3c-4.67-4.87-7-11.27-7-19.21c0-7.94,2.33-14.34,7-19.21
                C299.9,27.59,306.11,25.16,313.91,25.16z M302.76,65.73c1.57,1.44,3.33,2.49,5.3,3.15c1.97,0.67,3.9,1,5.8,1c1.9,0,3.83-0.33,5.8-1
                c1.97-0.67,3.75-1.7,5.35-3.1c3.6-3.27,5.4-8,5.4-14.21c0-6-1.8-10.67-5.4-14.01c-3-2.73-6.7-4.1-11.11-4.1
                c-7.2,0-12.21,3.24-15.01,9.71c-1,2.34-1.5,5.15-1.5,8.46c0,3.3,0.5,6.12,1.5,8.46S301.19,64.3,302.76,65.73z"/>
            <path class="syncron" d="M377.75,33.56c-5.87,0-11.34,3.2-16.41,9.61v30.02c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2s-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3
                c-1.27,0-2.34-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V30.26c0-1.33,0.43-2.43,1.3-3.3c0.87-0.87,1.93-1.3,3.2-1.3
                c1.27,0,2.35,0.43,3.25,1.3c0.9,0.87,1.35,1.97,1.35,3.3v4.1c2.67-2.8,4.97-4.77,6.9-5.9c3.8-2.2,7.42-3.3,10.86-3.3
                s6.25,0.52,8.46,1.55c2.2,1.04,4.07,2.45,5.6,4.25c3.13,3.67,4.7,8.27,4.7,13.81v28.42c0,1.27-0.45,2.33-1.35,3.2
                s-1.99,1.3-3.25,1.3c-1.27,0-2.33-0.43-3.2-1.3c-0.87-0.87-1.3-1.93-1.3-3.2V45.77c0-3.8-0.85-6.79-2.55-8.96
                C384.5,34.65,381.68,33.56,377.75,33.56z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path class="dot" d="M16.31,62.08h4c1.93,0,3.28,0.37,4.05,1.1c0.77,0.73,1.15,2.07,1.15,4v4.8c0,1.94-0.38,3.29-1.15,4.05
                c-0.77,0.77-2.12,1.15-4.05,1.15h-4c-1.94,0-3.29-0.38-4.05-1.15c-0.77-0.77-1.15-2.12-1.15-4.05v-4.8c0-1.93,0.38-3.27,1.15-4
                C13.02,62.45,14.37,62.08,16.31,62.08z"/>
        </g>
        </a>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Thank for your comment Sean. Following your advice will give a 3rd variant of the rendering. I added Imgur links in the OP and following your advice the rendering is producing more faint outlines compare to the original. Try and run my code in Chrome and Safari and you can see the the fill is causing the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Thanks for posting [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55646515/5351721).